# How to retrieve values of dynamically created views?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating views (spinner, editbox and datepicker) programatically (don't know the exact number and type from before). On Click of submit button, I need to retreive all the values from the views. And also know which value is for which view.

I eventually need to pass all these values to another activity.

How can I achieve this functionality.

Comment: can you show your codes too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this You may have a `List` of `View`s as a class member like this.

```
private List<View> viewList;
```

Add each of your view to this list when each `View` is created. Then you can easily loop over it to get the values.

Comment: So, here my viewList would contain all types of views. So how would I get values from it. What I mean is since spinner has getSelectedItem(), editText has getText() and so on. How to retreive these values without knowing what view is?

Comment: you can use `instanceOf` operator to check what kind of view is

Answer (score 0):

The click handler passes in a reference to the view that was clicked.  Just call to get its values.

If you really need to walk all of the things you made and check all the values, store them all in some data structure (hash, list, etc).  Keeping track of which is which should be part of that data structure.  But we can't really suggest a more detailed solution without knowing when and why you need to access them, and what they're used for.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a list with yout views (as suggested by R9j, which is a perfectly fine way to do it) it is also possible to get the root view of your activity using

```
View rootLayout= ((ViewGroup)findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0)
```

In this view all the views added by you will be, so you can go through the list of child-views

```
    for(int i=0; i<rootLayout.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        View child = rootLayout.getChildAt(i);
        if(child instanceof TextView)
        {
            int id= child.getId();
            if(id>500) //whatever check makes sense to you given the way you use ids
            {
                String content = ((TextView) child).getEditableText().toString();
            }
        }
    }
```

In this case I checked for TextView but any other type would be possible aswell, by giving IDs to the views when creating them you could recognize which View was supposed to have what information. [You may also use tags for that](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).

Note that, despide their name, IDs of views do not have to be unique.